# Jenkins Jacoco post build action

Tags: maven, jenkins, jacoco

I have the below dependency in my POM file

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.4.201502262128</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Below is the structure of my classes
src/main
src/test

I'm trying to run my functional test cases located at src/test and I want to ignore src/main

I've configured as below but it's not running on my test cases

[image]

Answer (score 0):

u need to add few other things along with jacoco to get code coverage. because jacoco doesn't get code reports directly.

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
        <sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>
        <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
        <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
    </properties>
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.18</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>run-unit-tests</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>test</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <skip>${skipUnitTests}</skip>
                                <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.18</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>run-integration-tests</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                <goal>verify</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <skip>${skipIntegrationTests}</skip>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

<profile>
            <id>sonar-coverage</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.7.4.201502262128</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <append>true</append>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>agent-for-ut</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>agent-for-it</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>jacoco-site</id>
                                <phase>verify</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>report</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
```

and If this doesn't show any code coverage, search if there is file named jacoco.exec in target folder of work-space of your project.